# Problems with Installation

Tags: installation, livedvd

I have downloaded Ubuntu *three* times; *twice* on a live DVD and *once* on my desktop. Now my DVD player is an sata drive so it doesn't register as a DVD it reads as another HD in the bios menu so I can't make it boot as a first boot device. The program doesn't have an executable or auto run so please help me. How do I install Ubuntu onto my computer?

Answer (score 2):

If you're having trouble burning a DVD that you can boot from, I would suggest instead creating a bootable USB drive.  USB drives are cheap, and they actually perform better as a boot environment than the discs do anyway.

If you're starting out from Windows, you'll need to download Unetbootin (from http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), which can either work with an ISO you've already downloaded, or just download one for you when you tell it you want to create an Ubuntu bootable USB drive.  Should be very easy and straight-forward.